# How to transpose a table in SQL - is UNPIVOT the only option?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an SQL table using this scheme

`[A Path] [B Path] [C Path] [D Path]`

I want to query the table with some `where` clause (it will match a single row) and present the result in a tabular form.

so if the matched row is

| A Path | B Path | C Path | D Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aValue | bValue | cValue | dValue |

I wish to present the results as

| File | Path |
| --- | --- |
| A | aValue |
| B | bValue |
| C | cValue |
| D | dValue |

I tried using SQL UNPIVOT but could not find the right syntax, I also suspect UNPIVOT will not serve my purpose as it needs some aggregation function. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Isn't there any other column you want to select? Otherwise, with more than one original row, you will get many rows for file A, many for file B etc. Don't you care which A belongs to which B?

Comment: The real answer is: _you don't_ (or rather: _you shouldn't_): SQL is designed around sets of tuples, whereas transposition is for matrices - and it's usually a presentation-layer concern anyway, which isn't SQL's responsibility. MS should have never added `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` to T-SQL imo: it has surprisingly little utility and because it still requires explicit values and defined column-names it isn't much better than a mix of unions-and-joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` is often far clearer than `UNPIVOT`

```sql
SELECT
  v.File,
  v.Path
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
  ('A', t.A_path),
  ('B', t.B_path),
  ('C', t.C_path),
  ('D', t.D_path)
) v(file, path);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your unpivot must be like this

But this approach will give for every row a new row, that are the same file with different path, so you might chekcif that is really what yut want

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    ([A Path] varchar(6), [B Path] varchar(6), [C Path] varchar(6), [D Path] varchar(6))
;
    
INSERT INTO mytable
    ([A Path], [B Path], [C Path], [D Path])
VALUES
    ('aValue', 'bValue', 'cValue', 'dValue')
;
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
SELECT  [File], [Path]  
FROM   
   (SELECT [A Path] as A, [B Path] as B, [C Path] as C, [D Path] AS D FROM  mytable ) t
UNPIVOT  
   ([Path] FOR [File] IN   
      (A,  B,  C,  D)  
)AS unpvt
```

| File | Path |
| --- | --- |
| A | aValue |
| B | bValue |
| C | cValue |
| D | dValue |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aWuxvZkC)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
select 'A' as file, a_path as path from mytable
union all
select 'B' as file, b_path as path from mytable
union all
select 'C' as file, c_path as path from mytable
union all
select 'D' as file, d_path as path from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option that will dynamically UNPIVOT virtually any table, view or ad-hoc query without having to use Dynamic SQL or enumerate all the columns.

**Example**

```
Select A.[Id]
      ,Item  = B.[Key]
      ,Value = B.[Value]
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select * 
                From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                Where [Key] not in ('Id','Other','Columns','ToExclude')
             ) B
```